Create a loop touching file with time increasing by one second
I have list of 50 files and I want to create a loop touching file with time increasing by one second.
Trying to test data staging policy and want to have those files created with different time (difference 2 seconds). The files already exists, so do not want to create a new set. Just using a simple loop
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1000}
do touch -d '1 Aug 2024 XXX' file_$i
done

How do I increase the time (XXX) in touch -d command?

"want to have those files created with different time" – With touch you can alter atime and/or mtime, then ctime gets updated automatically. Neither of these are birth/creation time. Several filesystems support btime/crtime, but AFAIK touch does not directly touch it. Even when it creates a file anew, btime is assigned automatically, not explicitly by touch. There are differences between systems, only some provide ways to change btime freely. What is your OS? Are you sure you mean "created"?

The GNU version of touch is very liberal in accepting date specifications. So it is sufficient to do:
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1000} ; do
   touch -d "1 Aug 2024 + $i seconds"  file_$i
done

